# how to limit some user to access my ERP system By user's MAC address?

Tags: php

Our company has a ERP system developed using php language. And,I just want to allow some users to access our ERP system. It is not feasible by username and password validation because a valid user may tell others username and password.

Should I limit our valid users by a user's PC MAC address? How to get a user's  PC MAC address, and post it to our erp system? Do I need to develop an application to implement it?

Comment: You need to read up on authentication and authorization security and understand what it means. Using a MAC address because someone might voluntarily give out their password is a point solution that won't make what you're doing any more secure.

Comment: Thank your reply. I want to register our valid users PC MAC address first. And when a user login our erp system, we will valid its username and password  and then valid the MAC address posted from login form. It is too tedious to  force a user to provide its PC MAC address. So, I want to develop an application to get a valid user's PC MAC address. is it possible?

Comment: MAC addresses can be spoofed too. This will not stop users giving away their MACs.  If you need  MAC level filtering try adding an access list to your router (I assume this is running on your company's  lan or private network). PHP can't get the MACs of clients.

Comment: Another solution is to log user actions...like what IP's they logged on from and review those from time to time and have a talk with the user that shared their credentials. You  have to make sure they all have static IPs ..or disable their account as soon as another IP logs on. It's important that users don't know about these security rules...because this can also be easily circumvented.

Comment: @lansen Yes, 
MAC addresses may be spoofed too. But It doesn't matter becouse We just don't want our erp system  been viewed arbitrarily. I am ready to develop a application using VB, using it to get user's MAC addresses, and posting it to server when login. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @andychang Could you use some sort of key file authentication akin to public/private key SSH login?

Comment: @jDo No, I am afraid not. It is not communications between servers. I just want to limit some clients  to access our erp systems. The clients's ip often be varied when their modem reboots. So I have to recogniize the valid user by their PC Mac Adrress.

Comment: @andychang public/private key authentication is not just a server-to-server thing; typically it's a client-to-server thing. Earlier, you wrote *"(...) posting it to server when login."* so clearly something is going across the network from a client to a server. Public/private key auth could probably work. It would mean that users don't need a password and can only access the ERP systems if they have a specific file on their computer; the file itself could/should be locked down via permission settings.

Comment: @jDo Suppose a valid user own a public key and can access my server, he may expose the public key to a invalid user.  So, how to avoid the invalid user access my server? That's the question.

Comment: @andychang do the clients access the server via the browser or via desktop application that has access to the local file system?